# Finding the coefficient of $x^0$ in $\left(\frac{x+1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1} - \frac{x-1}{x-x^{1/2}}\right)^{10}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> How do we find the coefficient of $x^0$ in this expression?
> $$\left(\frac{x+1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1} - \frac{x-1}{x-x^{1/2}}\right)^{10}$$

This problem is just very perplexing. I wrote down the $T_{r+1}$ for it as such:

$T_{r+1} = (-1)^r\;^nC_r\;(\frac{x+1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1})^{n-r}\;(\frac{x-1}{x-x^{1/2}})^r$

I tried plugging the expression into Wolfram Alpha, it showed me an [error](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Coefficient%20of%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ax%5E0%2F%2F%5D%20in%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%28%28%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E%282%2F3%29-x%5E%281%2F3%29%2B1%29%29-%28%28x-1%29%2F%28x-x%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29%29%5E10%20%2F%2F%5D). I tried a few other sites, but they were all in vain.

Ordinarily, there should be only one unknown term having $x$, whose power we equate to $0$, but that clearly isn't the case here. It should be solved without using Trinomial or Multinomial Theorem. Is there any way of doing so, and finding the coefficient of $x^0$?

Edit: Thanks to the users in the comments, I could identify the $a^3 + b^3$ and $a^2-b^2$ identities. I'm now getting the coefficient of $x^0$ as $210$, which is correct.

Comment: *Hint*: $\frac{x+1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1}=x^{1/3}+1$ and similarly $\frac{x-1}{x-x^{1/2}}=\dots$

Comment: Alternative hint: substitute $x=y^6$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Series++++%5B%28%28%28y%5E6%2B1%29%2F%28y%5E4-y%5E2%2B1%29%29-%28%28y%5E6-1%29%2F%28y%5E6-y%5E3%29%29%29%5E10%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{x+1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1} - \frac{x-1}{x-x^{1/2}}\right)^{10}$$

We can simplify both the terms as follows;

The first term $\left(\frac{x+1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1}\right)$, take $x^{\frac{1}{3}}=t$ and it simplifies to $x^{\frac{1}{3}}+1$

Similarly,

The second term $\left(\frac{x-1}{x-x^{1/2}}\right)$, take $x^{\frac{1}{2}}=t$ and it simplifies to $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}+1$

$$(x^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{-1}{2}})^{10}$$

Writing the general term;

$$T_{r+1}=\,^nc_r(x^{\frac{10-r}{3}})(-x^{\frac{-r}{2}})$$

$$T_{r+1}=(-1)^r\,^{10}c_r(x^{\frac{10-r}{3}-\frac{r}{2}})$$
$$T_{r+1}=(-1)^r\,^{10}c_r(x^{\frac{20-5r}{6}})$$

To get the coefficient of $x^0$, we can plug in $r=4$;

coefficient of $x^0=\,^{10}c_4=210$